# The application "name.dll" does not exist" trying to run a docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project I'm working on and I'm in the process of containerizing it while also learning docker, so I apologize in advance if this is a common issue, but I haven't personally found any solutions online.

The application itself runs, and I tried running the commands specified in the image and they work, however, when I try to run the Image I get an error saying the .dll does not exist

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish

# Runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=build /publish ./ 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "PDF_Reader_APIs.Server.dll" ]
```

**Error:**

```
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 --name pdf_manager_containerized pdf_manager_image
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application './publish/PDF_Reader_APIs.Server.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.
```

The container is still built even after the error, and when I check its files, the publish file is indeed there and it does contain the `PDF_Manager_APIs.Server.dll`, so I'm not entirely sure what's the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You say that `PDF_Manager_APIs.Server.dll` is in the image, but it's complaining about `PDF_Reader_APIs.Server.dll`

Comment: I mean, that's why I'm posting this lol. When opening the Image's directory, the publish folder is in the root and directly within it is PDF_Manager_APIs.Server.dll

Comment: But your Dockerfile has the entrypoint specified as `PDF_Reader_APIs.Server.dll`